# Toggle function to show and hide element associated with class

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have several divs on a page that have text hidden that I would like to show when a div element is clicked. How can I do this using classes for the divs?

Here is my html:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('team-member'); ?>>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(441,293)); ?>
    <div class="bio-button">BIO</div>   
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <h3><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3>
    <div class="team-text">
       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jquery:

```
$('.bio-button').toggle(function () {
   $('.team-text',this).show();
}, function () {
   $('.team-text',this).hide();
return false;
});
```

So again, I will have multiple divs for .team-member, .team-text is hidden, and will be shown when click on .bio-button.

What am I doing wrong in my jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.team-text` is not child element of the clicked element, you can you `siblings` and `toggle` effect methods:

```
$('.bio-button').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings('.team-text').toggle();
});
```

Note that as of jQuery 1.7 toggle event method has been deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Update:

```
$('.bio-button').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings('.team-text').show();
});

$('.team-text .button').click(function () {
   $(this).parent('.team-text').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But what if I wanted to add additional effects? For example if I wanted to use another button in the div that is now shown to 'close' that div?  That's why I was using the toggle function. Sorry, I should have said this in my original question.

Comment: Oh, ok. You would just make another function. Do you mind explaining the logic here with "this" and siblings?

Comment: @MGDTech You were using $(selector, context), but the target element is sibling of the clicked element, `this` refers to the clicked element and `siblings` selects the sibling element.

Answer (score 2):

`.toggle()` already performs its own show/hide. No need to build a function inside.

You can also target multiple class names:  `$('.bio-button, .team-text')`

Comment: That's toggle event method not toggle effect method.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` doesn't take two functions like that. Toggle just shows/hides them (with configurable paramters).  This is likely what you need:

```
$('.bio-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.team-text').toggle();
}
```